# Using Reed Solomon codes for constraint checking

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

I have a question regarding the (somewhat recent) paper: [Ligero](https://acmccs.github.io/papers/p2087-amesA.pdf).
In particular, let $\mathbb{F}$ be any finite field, $m,l\in\mathbb{N}$.
Say we have $x,y,z,a,b\in\mathbb{F}^{ml}$ satisfying:
$$
x\odot y+z\odot a=b,
$$
where $\odot$ means point-wise product, i.e $x\odot y=(x_1 y_1,\ldots,x_{ml}y_{ml})$.

To check that the above holds we do the following. We encode $x,y,z,a,b$ into $m\times l$ matrices $U^x,U^y,U^z,U^a,U^b$ in the following way:
for example, for $x$, we split it into $m$ vectors of length $l$, then the first row of $U^x$ is a Reed-Solomon encoding of $(x_1,\ldots,x_l)$.(This can be done in a number of ways, the easiest one is to take $p^x_1(y)=\sum_{i=0}^{l} y^ix_i$, then let $U^x_1=(p^x_1(\theta_1),\ldots,p^x_1(\theta_l))$ where $\theta_i\in\mathbb{F}$ are pairwise distinct.

For clarity, in general the $j$ row will be encoded as:
$$U^x_j=(p^x_j(\theta_1),\ldots,p^x_j(\theta_l)),\;p^x_j(y)=\sum_{i=0}^{l} y^ix_{(j-1)\cdot m+i}.$$

Once this is done, we check the constraint by computing:
$$
p_0=\sum_{i=0}^m p^x_i \cdot p^y_i
+ p^a_i \cdot p^z_i - p_i^b
$$

And we check if $p_0(\theta_i)=0,\forall 1\leq i \leq l$. (This doesn't guarantee that the constraint holds, but guarantees that it holds with certain probability).

My question is the following: why does it follow from $x\odot y+z\odot a=b$ that $p_0=0$?
This is not trivial for me. Any help is appreciated.